# apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev ... fails cause of HTTP 404

Tags: apache2, debian

I own a Debian Lenny 5.0 and try to install Apache development headers.

This command "apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev" tries to call not existing URLs like:

http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1-dev_1.2.12-5_amd64.deb

But the following exists when I list the files of the parent directory:

http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1-dev_1.2.12-5+lenny2_amd64.deb

What to do for me?

Answer (score 1):

Your local package index is out-of-date, meaning that you are trying to install a package version that no longer exists on the package server (repository in Debian talk). To update it, run ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/)) `apt-get update` and retry the install.